# How to use a Math.random function in association with an IF statement

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

I am trying to output different messages based upon the output of a function that uses the math.random function to generate a number between 1 and 4.

```
function roll()
{
return Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1)  
}
```

When a button is pressed the function is called and a global variable 'a' is assigned to the result of the roll function.

```
var a;
function buttonPressed() {
roll() 
a = roll() 
answertq = (x*y);
```

The following code essentially means that if the answer the user provides in the answer box is correct then depending upon the result of the roll function output a different message as below.

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById("inputVal").value) == answertq) 
{
    if (a=1) 
    {
        window.alert("Very good!");
    }
    else if (a=2)
    {
        window.alert("Excellent!");
    }
    else if (a=3)
    {
        window.alert("Correct, Nice work");
    }
    else if (a=4)
    {
        window.alert("Correct - Keep up the good work");
    }

}
```

Except that when I do this I always get the first response ("Very good!") every time the question is correct. Meaning that there is something wrong with the roll function in that it keeps assigning 1 to the global variable 'a' or something else I have not spotted. Any help would be much appreciated. I have provided two screenshots of the problem below.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/28YcV.jpg "Example One"
[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANG2t.jpg "Example Two"

Comment: Please learn about the [`switch(){}` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: An alternative approch is to store messages in an array and access it with a random index: `var success_msgs = ["Correct", "You got it", ...]` followed by `success_msg[roll()]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Except that when I do this I always get the first response ("Very
>   good!") every time the question is correct.

The reason is because you are not comparing the values you are assigning. `==` is for comparison and `=` is for assignment.

Try this:

```
if (a==1) 
    {
        window.alert("Very good!");
    }
    else if (a==2)
    {
        window.alert("Excellent!");
    }
    else if (a==3)
    {
        window.alert("Correct, Nice work");
    }
    else if (a==4)
    {
        window.alert("Correct - Keep up the good work");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works perfectly now. I did not realise that there was a difference between the two.

Comment: @Skywhisky:- You are welcome! P.S. Also do read about switch:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `a==1` not assign `a=1`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an array for your messages?
That way you can use the random number as an index for the array.

```
var msg = [
    "Very good!",
    "Excellent!",
    "Correct, Nice work",
    "Correct - Keep up the good work"
];

function randomMsg (){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    alert(msg[random]);
}
```

edit: arrays are zero based so no "+1"

Comment: This a great way of doing it but I'm struggling to implement it into my own program. But thank you for your help its much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All of your if statements are using the assignment operator "=" not the comparison operator "==":

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById("inputVal").value) == answertq) {
    if (a==1) {
        window.alert("Very good!");
    }
```

etc...